# React Native Maps Rendering current location breaks when I restart App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

currently with my app I have it so that it asks the user for location perms and if they accept it then fetches their location. Currently however when I render the map with a set region it works and when the change the code to their location that the code fetches it changes to their location. When i reset the app or Expo the app crashes because the state is undefined. How can I get passed this? Here is the code:

```
const Map = () => {

  // Get permissons for using user location
  const [location, setLocation] = useState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const getPermissions = async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        console.log("Please grant location permissions");
        return;
      }

      let currentLocation = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(currentLocation.coords);

      console.log("Location:");
      console.log(currentLocation);
    };
    
    getPermissions();

  }, []);

    return(
//Will change this Mapview to users current location
//Will display about 0 - 30 miles away from used depending on user settings.
    <MapView 
    initialRegion={
      { 
          //I when I restart the app with latitude and longitude as latitude: latitude: location.coords.latitude longitude: location.coords.longitude app crashes cause the state is cleared. 
          latitude: 24.8607,
          longitude: 67.0011,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}
     style ={styles.map}/>
  );
}
```

I want the app to constantly be set to the users location even if the app is restarted

Comment: Do you share your full example? I do not see the `location` state like a prop in `MapView`. Where are you using this `location` state?

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't defined an initial value for your `location state`, it is initialized with a `null` value. Thus `location.coords` is `undefined`.

To fix the issue, when passing the latitude and longitude props to the `MapView` component, you can check if location isn't null or undefined, and pass its values to the `MapView` component.

The Map won't re-render if you change the `initialRegion` prop since it is used for initial rendering. To update the Map location after the location state is updated, you can use the `region` prop. It will cause a render in MapView when its value is changed. And the new region will be shown.

This can be approached by rewriting the props as below:

```
<MapView 
    initialRegion={{ 
          latitude: !!location ? location.coords.latitude : 24.8607,
          longitude: !!location ? location.coords.longitude : 67.0011,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}
     region={{ 
          latitude: !!location ? location.coords.latitude : 24.8607,
          longitude: !!location ? location.coords.longitude : 67.0011,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}
     style ={styles.map}
/>
```

This way, once the permission is acquired and the state is updated with new values, the `MapView` will receive the new props and renders.

You should use `initialRegion` for showing a default region before the `location` is updated. After that, the `region` prop can update the view.

Comment: Woah it worked and made complete sense!! I appreciate it man. I dont have much js experience so still getting used to the syntax and new operators. Thanks!